# What format is it? There are any way to translate to readable text in Python?

Tags: python

What format is it? There are any way to translate to readable text in Python?

```
\xfe\xff\x00M\x00i\x00c\x00r\x00o\x00s\x00o\x00f\x00t\x00\xae\x00 \x00W\x00o\x00r\x00d\x00 \x002\x000\x001\x009
```

Comment: Seems like that's a string that was encoded in UTF-16 big endian with BOM. Assuming that stuff comes from a `bytes` variable called `data`, you should be able to decode it using `data.decode('UTF-16')`, which gives me `u'Microsoft\xae Word 2019'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is UTF-16 encoding. You can decode it like so:

```py
s = b'\xfe\xff\x00M\x00i\x00c\x00r\x00o\x00s\x00o\x00f\x00t\x00\xae\x00 \x00W\x00o\x00r\x00d\x00 \x002\x000\x001\x009'
print(s.decode('utf16'))  # Microsoft® Word 2019
```

Comment: I got that values in a string, i convert it with bytes() function and show a Traceback "string argument without an encoding". Finally, i encode the  s = bytes(s.encode())   and showme letters in japanese. How can i resolve that?